# Calling a function from inside a function

Tags: python, function, plot, nested, nested-function

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *



c = 299792458 # m/s 
lamda = 643.5 *10**-9 # m

def read_file(filename):
    text_array = loadtxt(filename)
    time = text_array[:, 0]
    obs_lambda = text_array[:, 1]
    flux = text_array[:, 2]
    return [flux,time,obs_lambda]


def rad_vel(data):
    v_r = zeros(len(data[2]))
    for i in range(len(data[2])):
        v_r = c*(((data[2][i] - lamda))/(lamda))
    print v_r
    plot(data[1],v_r)
    show()
    return v_r

    test1 = read_file("test.txt")
    print test1
```

When I called the function it was a difference in dimensions with v_r and time. len(time) or len(data[2]) was an **array** with  5087 elements, but v_r was a **scalar**. Can't really understand how v_r is a **scalar**?

Comment: Any reason why you're nesting the other function? In any case, `rad_vel` is unreachable as it comes after the `return` statement of the enclosing function. What exactly are you up to?

Comment: How else can I call read_file(filename) inside rad_vel() to transfer the time and obs_lambda?

Comment: I am guessing that you want to return `rad_vel` from `read_file`. That would work, but I would not suggest actually using that pattern in this situation.

Comment: You should have completely separate (not nested) functions `rad_vel` and `read_file`. You can then call one from the other.

Comment: Yes, I want to plot (time,v_r)

Comment: Yes tried not nesting, but was not sure how to call it then to get the plot as output

Answer (score 0):

I can't try this without the file or modules, but here's one that uses a class.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
def readFileData(filename): # Reads file
    text_array = loadtxt(filename)
    ...
    flux = ... # array read from .txt
    time = ... # array read from .txt
    obs_lambda = ... # array read from .txt
    return [flux,time,obs_lambda]

def rad_vel(data): # Finds radial velocity
    for i in range(len(data[2])):
        v_r = data[2][i] - 2
    plot(data[1],v_r)
    show()
    return v_r
textData=readFileData("test.txt")
print(rad_vel(textData))
```

Comment: `v_r` should probably be a list.

Comment: It's hard to tell if it even works without knowing what modules are needed or what the text file is like. All I did was take the two functions and make them into classes.

Comment: I am not very familiar with classes so it will be easiest only using functions

Comment: Yes v_r is a list

Comment: Thanks! Classes basically let you make an object that you make the functions on how to interact with it. I'll see if I can make it into functions, but it's hard to do without the text file to test it.

Comment: I understand. The text file is just 3 columns with about 100 lines of numbers. Column 1: 100 flux values, Column 2: 100 time values, Column: 100 lambda values. No text only numbers

Comment: I just changed the code in my answer. Would that work?

Comment: ooh, thank you.  I also think nesting was a mistake. This looks very good and simple. I will try it now :D

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I had a small error with different dimensions between data[2] and v_r

Comment: I tried adding v_r as an array with same length as data[2], but still got a scalar

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. What were you adding v_r to?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here maybe what you want. I guess you want a helper function

```
def read_file(filename): # Reads file
    def rad_vel(flux,time,obs_lambda): # Finds radial velocity

        # should you declare v_r in here? 
        v_r = 0  

        for i in range(len(obs_lambda)):
            v_r = obs_lambda[i] - 2
        plot(time,v_r)
        show()
        return v_r

    text_array = loadtxt(filename)
    ...
    flux = ... # array read from .txt
    time = ... # array read from .txt
    obs_lambda = ... # array read from .txt
    return rad_vel(flux,time,obs_lambda)
```

Comment: Looks good for 1 function, but in my program I will have 3-4  functions inside read_file(). Then it may get more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Along with other values you have to return the inside function too like

```
return [rad_vel,flux,time,obs_lambda]

test1 = read_file("test.txt")

test1[0]('test.txt')
```